# Keep Track of already summed tuples sql

Tags: sql

If we have a table with values for a and b, is there a way to only add up the b's if its not a duplicate a? For example

```
a b
1 2
2 3
2 3
```

so we would get only 5 (instead of 8)

A sort of

```
select sum(b if unique a),
from table
where ...
```

Comment: What value should be adde in case of `a = 2` and first `b = 3` and second  `b = 5`? Does `a` is equal `2 + 3` or `2 + 5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query selects the lowest value of `b` for each group `a`

```
select min(b) min_b
from mytable
group by a
```

You can then sum those values by selecting the sum from a derived table

```
select sum(min_b) from (
    select min(b) min_b
    from mytable
    group by a
) t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82c5/1

Answer (score 1):

You  haven't specified your RDBMS, but if you are using a database which supporting window functions like SQL Server, you can query the unique rows first by using `WITH` clause and `ROW_NUMBER()` function and then get the `SUM` out of that.

```
;WITH C AS(
  SELECT a, b,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY a) AS Rn
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT SUM(b) FROM C
WHERE Rn = 1
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12a0a/1)</kbd>